# AppFabric caching on build server - dilemma with assembly referencing

Tags: msbuild, jenkins, appfabric

We have recently added AppFabric as a caching option in our project (Windows server version, not Azure cloud).  The project thus now has a dependancy on Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll and .Core.dll.

Our build server is Windows 2003 and thus AppFabric cache cannot be installed onto it, thus these assemblies are not available.

Short of including the afore mentioned assemblies as explicit binaries in our SVN repository, and referencing them directly (yuck), are there any suggestions as to how to build the project?

Secondly, if we checked in the binaries, performed the build then deleted them from the output folder, is there a way to force .NET to search the %windir%\system32\AppFabric\ folder for the assemblies?

MS do not register them in the GAC...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is using an assembly that can't be installed on your build server, then the solution is to upgrade your build server to Windows 2008.

Comment: Yes that was actually an option I was trying to avoid but it does seem to be the most logical solution

Comment: I've reluctantly accepted your answer. Logically I guess this is the best solution - the IT boys are just afraid to touch that server